# Kubernetes w/Docker For Windows: How to reference private registry?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm using docker for windows on my local laptop, and I'm trying to mimic a dev installation of kubernetes by using the "run kubernetes' setting on the same laptop.  One thing that's awkward is the docker registry.  I have a docker registry container running in-cluster that I can push to no problem from the laptop, but when the docker-for-windows kubernetes controller needs to 'pull' an image, I'm not sure how to reference the registry: I've tried referencing the registry using the laptops netbios name, with various DNS suffixes, but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You would use the internal cluster DNS, as managed by the Service object you probably created for the registry. All Services are available inside the cluster via `$name.$namespace.svc.cluster.local` (technically `cluster.local` is the cluster domain however this is the default and most common value by far).

Answer (score 0):

in kubernetes create a secret, called regsecret for example,

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regsecret --docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-pword> --docker-email=<your-email>
```

Creating a Pod that uses your Secret

Here is a configuration file for a Pod that needs access to your secret data:

{% include code.html language="yaml" file="private-reg-pod.yaml" ghlink="/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/private-reg-pod.yaml" %}

Copy the contents of private-reg-pod.yaml to your own file named my-private-reg-pod.yaml. In your file, replace  with the path to an image in a private repository.

Example Docker Hub private image:

`janedoe/jdoe-private:v1`

To pull the image from the private repository, Kubernetes needs credentials. The  imagePullSecrets field in the configuration file specifies that Kubernetes should get the credentials from a Secret named regsecret.

Create a Pod that uses your Secret, and verify that the Pod is running:

```
kubectl create -f my-private-reg-pod.yaml
kubectl get pod private-reg
```

from the following link,

https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/